# Using hangfire queue counters increment

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have a high traffic news portal, and one of requirements is to increment article view counters upon each article load. Until now, we just incremented numbers in real time, but I think it started to affect our performance.

I was thinking to use hangfire and fire and forget tasks in a queue, so we reduce load to our SQL servers.

Is this a good practice, and will Hangfire database become quite large over time with transaction logs and list of all successful tasks?

Comment: I think hangfire here is a sledgehammer to crack a nut. What are you hosting on? If it's AWS you could use DynamoDB or Redis or Redshift.

Comment: We are already using hangfire for recurring tasks, so it seems practical to use it for this as well. We are self hosting. 10 web servers behind haproxy.

Comment: Does your Hangfire instance have it's own SQL server?

Comment: It's has it's own dabatabase, but not SQL server. SQL Server is hosted on quite powerful dedicated machine.